# async task for get data from firebase

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have applied to run video from YouTube

My problem is that I put my youtube videos links on Firebase

but when start activity View YouTube is not working because it takes the value of the variable video for youtube vedio load before getting the value of Firebase

I want a way to get value before entering the Youtube code

thats my code :

```
    private TextView mvalueview1;
private Firebase mref;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;
private String x;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //fullscreenANDtoolbar();

    setContentView(R.layout.watch_youtube);


    mref = new Firebase("Link_of_firebase_value");
    mvalueview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
                  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mvalueview1.setText(value);
            x = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

 youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeview);
     final TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    txtView.setText(x);
    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        final String VedioUrl = txtView.getText().toString();

        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VedioUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };
    youTubePlayerView.initialize("API_KEY", onInitializedListener);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Rxjava library to chain all actions one after another - 
you get video path from database first, then wait until player is ready and then wait until both of those tasks complete by .zip().first() operator and as response start playing video